# Como enviar parâmetros de um form usando Express e Node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express.js, route

Olá, eu estou tentando enviar via post os dados de um formulário usando Express, segue o código abaixo

**index.html**

```
<form action="insere" method="post">
            <p><h4> Título </h4>   <input type="text" name="titulo" id="titulo" size="40" maxlength="30" placeholder="Digite o título da tarefa"/> </p> 

            <p><h4>Descrição</h4> <textarea name="descricao" id="descricao" cols="50" rows="3" placeholder="Deixe uma breve descrição sobre sua tarefa"></textarea> </p> 

            <p> 
                <h4>Grau de importância(quanto maior o número, maior a importância)</h4>
                <input type="radio" name="urgencia" value="2"> Muito
                <input type="radio" name="urgencia" value="1" checked> Médio
                <input type="radio" name="urgencia" value="0"> Pouco
            </p>

            <p> 
                <h4>Como irá realizar essa tarefa</h4>
                <select name="tipoTarefa" id="select"> 
                    <option value="2"> Número vezes </option> 
                    <option value="1"> Hora </option> 
                    <option value="0"> Minuto </option> 
                </select>
                <input type="text" name="numeroRepeticoes" id="options" size="40" maxlength="5" placeholder="Em quantas vezes você pretende fazer?"/> </p> 
            </p>

            <p><button type="submit"> Criar </button></p>
        </form>
```

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))


const db = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : 'localhost',
        user     : 'root',
        password : '',
        database : 'metas'
});

db.connect( (err)  => {//Conectando
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log('MySQL conectado...');
});

app.get('/select', (req, res) => {
        let sql = "SELECT * FROM tarefas";
        db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
                if(err) throw err;
                res.send(result);
        })
})

app.post('/insere', (req, res) => {
        let post = 
                {titulo: req.body.titulo, 
                descricao: req.body.descricao, 
                grau: req.body.urgencia, 
                tipoRealizacao: req.body.tipoTarefa, 
                repeticoes: req.body.numeroRepeticoes
                }
        let sql = 'INSERT INTO tarefas SET ?';
        let query = db.query(sql, post, (err, result) => {
                if(err) throw err;
                res.send("Post added");
        })
})


app.listen('3000', () => { console.log("Server iniciado") } );
```

Como dá para perceber eu estou usando mysql, além disso estou usando o wampp, na porta 3306, a questão é que quando eu dou submit no form ele fala que a URL requisitada não está naquele servidor, é como se ele não conseguisse ir até o localhost:3000 que é onde o app está escutando, alguém pode me ajudar por favor? Não sei se talvez faça diferença mas o index está na página public e o app na pasta src. Obrigado

Comment: Já experimentas-te com `action="/insere"`?

Comment: Já sim, já tentei muitas coisas desse tipo

Comment: Como você está renderizando sua index?

Coloca na sua variável `post` ela como igual a `req.body` e dá um `console.log(post)`, veja se está chegando os campos na variável